# The emulator doesn't run in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, windows-xp, emulation, startup

When I select the start button in my application, Visual studio displays back to me:

```
"AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Nexus_4_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none"
```

and the emulator doesn't start.

Comment: Paste this command in DOS and check output...